# Socket.io is getting a 403 error on my website

Tags: nginx, socket.io, raspberry-pi3, aframe, easyrtc

Check https://www.winsteadworks.com console for the error.

My website is on my raspberry pi 3 using `nginx` webserver to host my website. I am having trouble getting `NAF` (Networked AFrame) to work correctly. What I am trying to do is get `Easyrtc` to work correctly so I can interact/communicated with other players on my website. I got this to work correctly while it was hosted locally on my other computer, but when I moved it to the raspberry pi and tried to put it online was when I started to have issues.
I am getting a `403` error for my `socket.io` for `easyrtc`. On my website if you look in the console you will see the errors start to stack for `socket.io`.

**What I have tried:**
Check port forwarded ports
tried to add port 8080 to my config in `/var/www/html/winsteadworks.com` but kept getting errors
Checked my firewall settings for both my router and my raspberry pi
I also tried reconfiguring different files but still have had no luck.

**The error:**

> socket.io.min.js:1 GET https://winsteadworks.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MJ1pNxu 403 (Forbidden)

This error continues over and over every second and won't stop until you close the page.

I am at a loss here until I know a few things:

1. Why am I getting this error? Is this a `nginx` issue, is this an `easyrtc` issue, is this a raspberry pi issue, or is it a port forwarding problem (yes port 8080 is forwarded)?
2. What direction do I need to go in order to problem solve this?

Or I will just take the short, sweet and simple answer! Thanks in advance for you time.